# PHP Command Line Loads Different Modules than PHP through Apache

Tags: php, apache, leveldb

So I have installed LevelDB and the relevant bindings. I have created a file, phpinfo.php in the root web directory with a single

When run from the command line...

```
php phpinfo.php | grep php.ini
```

I get...

```
Loaded Configuration File -> /etc/php.ini
```

When run from the command line...

```
php phpinfo.php | grep leveldb
```

I get...

```
leveldb support => enabled 
leveldb extension version => 0.1.4 leveldb
library veraion => 1.13
```

However, when I open http://{site}/phpinfo.php

I still get:

```
Loaded Configuration File -> /etc/php.ini
```

But no leveldb support.

It appears to be using the same php.ini in both cases. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to restart Apache.

Comment: which os is this on, and how did you install apache and leveldb?